# Is it possible to automatically reload Dev Tools Console on VS Code save

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio-code, console, devtools

As I'm writing in VS Code and I save, I'd like the console to reload rather than add all console logs to the bottom of the list in the console. Is it possible to have the console "clear" and reload all logs on each save?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to `console` of dev tools and open **console settings** at the right corner (which is in blue color as in the given image). Then uncheck `preserve log`

[image]

Comment: This hasn't quite solved the problem. To clarify: When localhost is reloaded it reloads the console aswell. Is there a way to have that functionality when i save in vscode? my basic understanding is that when I save, localhost does some kind of rerender, but doesnt clear and reload the console.